# Replacing tact switches on MPC2000xl. Need help with one not responsive

Tags: pcb, soldering

[image]I have replaced 40 small tact switches on my MPC2000xl four of which were not responsive. After some cleaning and desoldering I was able to get 3 working again. The last one has a burned contact pad that may be an issue. Is there any way to repair the burned pad if that's what is causing the issue? I've checked to make sure there were no broken connections and all look good. Thank you in advance for any help.
[image: MPC2000xl PCB]

Comment: That's not burned, that's missing. You (or someone else working on the board) lifted that pad while desoldering the old switch. It doesn't appear that that pad was connected to anything, though; what does the other side of it look like?

Comment: @Hearth Yes, that would be me that removed it by accident while soldering. I added a photo of the front.

Comment: Oh, it's a single-sided board? There  won't be any issues then, just solder the other three pins and it should be fine.

Comment: Looks like too much heat overall. Apart from that the classic mistake is to turn it wrong by 90°. Have your multimeter next to you when soldering.

Answer (score 0):

You've lifted a pad. This usually means you used too much heat when desoldering the component.

Judging by your photo, that pad wasn't actually connected to anything, so you should be able to just solder in the other three leads and it'll work fine. It might be a little wobbly; that fourth solder joint would have given it better mechanical stability.

Comment: I just soldered the 3 and still no response. I'm out of time to work on it so the next update I can give is next Thursday or Friday. Thank you for your help so far. I appreciate you.